# Python - importing a function from another file, and the running primary file on task scheduler as batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I can't trace problem for this as it runs completely fine when I run the Python Script in my text editor itself. However, when it's scheduled as a batch file, it doesn't work.

My pseudo code is like such: I have a main.py that imports a function from another file in the same folder.

```
from functions import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    secondary_function() # My function from the secondary file.
```

Meanwhile, `secondary_function` is written to invoke various slack alerts throughout the function, which is how I know whether it's being run at all.

When I run this script from within my Atom text editor, it works right, and the function imported from the other file is great.

When I put it on task scheduler as a batch file, though, running the batch file does not also run the function imported from the other file. Strange stuff and there isn't an error message for me to work off of.

Comment: check ```print(__name__)```?

Comment: Yep, one of the first things I did! `__name__` seems to be correct.